# Compute a melting temperature in viennaRNA?

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, rna, thermodynamics

Posting here to get views, but may be more appropriate for bioinformatics or chemistry SE.

There are a variety of utilities such as [biopython](https://biopython.org/docs/1.76/api/Bio.SeqUtils.MeltingTemp.html) or primer3 that compute melting temperatures.

However, tools for performing thermodynamic calculations on oligonucleotides should in theory be able to do this. ViennaRNA is one such popular tool, which although it has famously difficult documentation, [I can't find anything there about melting temps](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/ViennaRNA/doc/html/group__model__details.html#gab4b11c8d9c758430960896bc3fe82ead).

Frankly, I would trust Vienna more than some of the other tools, and I'd like to compute all my oligo stuff in one place.

It seems like I should be able to back-calculate a melting temperature from a delta G along with a series of parameters about concentrations etc. I found some equations that solve for Tm in terms of enthalpy and entropy, but I'm not sure how to get those values from Vienna either, which prefers to just give you the overall deltaG.

Can anyone clarify how to compute from ViennaRNA:

1. Enthalpy of folding
2. Entropy of folding
3. Tm

For context, I am mostly interested in using ViennaRNA's RNAlib via the Python API.

Comment: Have you seen this [table of programs](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/documentation.html#programs) in ViennaRNA? I don't know exactly which one should be used, but there seems to be several that calculate interaction energy between two RNAs. For melting temperature, you [can use](https://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/NNDB/help.html) $T_\mathrm{M} = \Delta H^\circ/(\Delta S^\circ + R \ln C_T)$. However, I am slightly worried if that is the best approach as you cannot change the sodium concentration in ViennaRNA, which

Comment: [significantly affects](https://eu.idtdna.com/pages/education/decoded/article/understanding-melting-temperature-(t-sub-m-sub-)) the melting temperature.

Comment: thanks @Domen, I clarified in the ticket now that I am using the RNAlib API rather than vienna programs. I would accept using one of those binaries if needed (though it's clunkier than I'd like), but I'll return again to the fact that I'm not sure how to compute either $\Delta H$ (enthalpy) or $\Delta S$ (entropy). None of those programs seem to do that, and searching the API docs or the viennarna docs leaves me empty-handed.

Comment: Just FYI, `biopython` is now at [version 1.81](https://pypi.org/project/biopython/). The docs you linked to were from 1.76 (I'm not sure if this API has changed since 2019 or not). You can always find the latest version of that page [here](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.SeqUtils.MeltingTemp.html), and it'll show you the specific version in the lower left.